# properties of projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression, projection, projection-matrices

For any $n \times p$ matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ such that $B^{\top} B$ is invertible, define the projection matrix $P_B$ as
$$
    P_B = B (B^{\top} B)^{-1} B^{\top} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}.
$$
Now consider four matrices as follows
$$
    B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p_1}, \qquad C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p_2}, \qquad C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p_3}.
$$
What I want to do is find the relationship between $P_{[B, C, D]}$ with $[B, C, D] \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (p_1 + p_2 + p_3)}$ and $P_{[B, D]}$ with $[B, D] \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (p_1 + p_3)}$. I wonder whether there exists some simple expressions for the difference
$$
    P_{[B, C, D]} - P_{[B, D]}?
$$
Here the assumptions we have is the inverses of matrices in $P_{[B, C, D]}$ and $P_{[B, D]}$ exist. Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

PS:
I found some formula of Inverse of a 3x3 block matrix, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2950054/1018088), and tried several times. I wonder there exists another approach to solve this problem more easily.

Comment: But $B^TB$ is not always invertible.

Comment: This question only makes sense we know that $[B,C,D]$ has linearly independent columns or if we use the more flexible definition for the projection matrix, $P = BB^\dagger$, where $B^\dagger$ is the Moore Penrose pseudoinverse of $B$.

Comment: In general, it is not true that the product $PQ$ of projection matrices $P,Q$ will itself be a projection matrix

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you so much! The previous statement in my question was not clear. Now I have updated it. Here the projection matrix uses the definition in the question, and we do not impose any restriction on the block matrix $[B, C, D]$.