# Inverse of block tridiagonal positive definite symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I have to compute the following matrix inverse

$$ \left( \begin{bmatrix}2\bf{B} &  -\bf{B} & \bf{0} \\ -\bf{B} & 2\bf{B}& -\bf{B}  \\\bf{0} & -\bf{B}& \bf{B}
 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}\bf{X_1} &  \boldsymbol{0} &\bf{0} \\ \bf{0} & \bf{X_2}& \bf{0}  \\\bf{0} & \bf{0}& \bf{X_3}
\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1} $$

where $\bf{B}$ and the  matrices $\bf{X_i}$ for $i=1,2,3$ are square symmetric positive definite of dimension  $N \times N$. Furthermore $\bf{B}$ is diagonal. I want to understand if the blocks of the inverse can be written as a combination of my original matrices. These blocks would be variances and covariances of random vectors, which are my objects of interest.

I think I can exploit in some way the fact that the matrix is tridiagonal, symmetric and pd but I didn't get anything useful by now.

Comment: why should it be invertible in the first place?

Comment: @sb945 it is the sum of two pd symmetric matrices

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix

Comment: @KBS thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seem to address my question, at least to my understanding...

Comment: There are explicit formulas for inverses of block matrices.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the partitioned inverse formula, but it is for 2x2 matrices don't know if, and how I could generalize it to a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Furthermore, that formula doesn't exploit the fact that the matrix is symmetric and tridiagonal which I think should help. looking here for example https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0613045 (theorem 3.4)

Comment: this seems too complicated as well https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950054/inverse-of-a-3x3-block-matrix

Comment: I need closed form expression for the blocks of the inverse which are variances and covariances of random vectors

Comment: The formula extends to 3×3 block matrices by applying the methods 2 times. It does not matter whether it exploits or not symmetric structure as the inverse is unique. Note, however, that admits several equivalent expressions.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/140080/116107)

Comment: yes thank you, it seems very related but x,y,z are random variables in that case, not random vectors

Comment: @Giorgetto You could write this matrix in the form $P(I + M^{-1})P^T$, where $M,P$ can each be written in terms of the $X_i$ and $B$. I'm not sure if this is a helpful change for whatever you're trying to do, though.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks, but I think it is not very helpful in my case